# Getting no output with a simple bteq code in windows powershell

Tags: powershell, output, bteq

Getting no output from the below code:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\System32> $PWD = import-Clixml -path "C:\BCBS\cred.xml";
    $BTEQ
    ".logon dbname\username,$PWD
      select infokey from dbc.dbcinfo
    .logoff"
    $BTEQ| bteq 
 
   ## $BTEQ
  
.logon dbname\username,System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
      select infokey from dbc.dbcinfo
    .logoff
BTEQ 16.20.00.07 (32-bit) Thu Feb 25 08:46:56 2021 PID: 16336
 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
 *** BTEQ exiting due to EOF on stdin.
 *** Exiting BTEQ...
 *** RC (return code) = 0
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're passing any input to `bteq`. Did you mean to write `$BTEQ = ".logon ..."`?

Comment: Do not use `$PWD` as self-defined variable name because it is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#pwd):  _Contains a path object that represents the full path of the current directory._

Comment: Thanks..  I've made the changes.  $pd = import-Clixml -path "C:\BCBS\cred.xml";
    $BTEQ =  ".logon ptdbia\a0s0m9,$pd ; 
                select infokey from dbc.dbcinfo;
                .logoff"
    $BTEQ| bteq

Comment: +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.logon dbname\username,
  *** BTEQ exiting due to EOF on stdin.
 *** Exiting BTEQ...
bteq :  *** CLI error: MTDP: EM_NOHOST(224): name not in HOSTS file or names database.
At line:5 char:12
+     $BTEQ| bteq
+            ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ( *** CLI error:...names database.:String) [],  *** Return code from CLI is: 224
 *** Error: Logon failed!
 
 *** RC (return code) = 8